# Would it be possible to transform power using capacitors instead of coils?

Tags: electricity

Would it be possible to use capacitors to transform electrical tension (up or down), in the following way?

Let's say you have a 10v battery, and you want to transform the tension up to 40 v.
First, you connect the battery in parallel with two capacitors, and charge them to 10 volt each. Then you connect the capacitors serially so you'll have a total of 20 v. You use these two capacitors to charge two other capacitors (connected in parallel), so that they'll have 20 v each. Then you connect these two capacitors serially, so that you have a total of 40 v, and then you continue in the same manner until you have reached the desired level of voltage. This thought experiment assumes that the capacitors are mechanically reconnected, but this could be automated using transistors to regulate the direction of flow.

Would this work, and if so, in what type of applications can you find this method of transformation?

Comment: Yes, but [there is already a simple and efficient way to do this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boost_converter).

Comment: https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/725